# Redmine/Ruby/Rails - Use custom helper methods inside of another custom helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine, helper, redmine-plugins

I don't know Ruby&Rails, but I would like to build a small custom Redmine plugin for my personal needs. 
And I have faced with the problem which might look quite straightforward for Ruby experts.
I have two helpers (modules):

- `helper1`
- `helper2`

And I would like to use `helper1.method1` inside of `helper2.method3`.
I have tried following to achieve this:

- simply call method `helper1.method1` inside `helper2.method3`, with thoughts that relations resolved automatically - didn't work;
- require `helper1` inside `helper2` by `require '../../relative/path'`- didn't worked;
- require `helper1` inside `helper2` by `require '../../relative/path'`- didn't worked;
- included `helper1` inside `helper2`- didn't worked

I have tried to find information how proper to call a method from one custom helper inside of another custom helper but didn't found any relevant results. The most of results were about how to call custom helper method inside view, controller, settings view.

So, could somebody explain to me how properly use methods from one custom helper inside of another one?

Best, regards.

Comment: I think you can try to include both helper modules to you controller class (for example https://github.com/twinslash/redmine_omniauth_google/blob/c4c79f5ab5599a6d963bb57131c9065bd2bf921e/app/controllers/redmine_oauth_controller.rb#L5-L6). Not sure but I think if methods from included helpers are accessible in controller then these methods can be called from each other.

Answer (score 1):

For common functionality I would suggest to

1. create a module in the lib folder  (e.g. `lib/my_plugin/common_code.rb`)
2. require it in the plugins init.rb:

   ```
   ActionDispatch::Callbacks.to_prepare do 
     require 'my_plugin/common_code'
   end
   ```
3. include it in each helper it is needed

   ```
   include MyPlugin::CommonCode
   ```